# In plain C, without using strlen or any library function that uses strlen, how do you find whether one string is contained in another?

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization

I say no use of `strlen` for efficiency purposes. Because if you use `strlen` then you've already iterated over a string and the best algorithms always iterate over a given container no more than once. So help me think how I would implement a function

```
bool contains ( char * s1, char * s2 ) 
{
   // ... 
}
```

**Attempt:**

```
bool contains ( char * s1, char * s2 ) 
{
   // returns true or false depending on whether s1 is contained in s2

   // define that every string contains the empty string
   if ( !*s1 ) return true;

   // search for substrings of s2 that equal s1
   bool flag = true;
   while ( *s2 ) 
   {
       char * c = s1; 
       while ( *c++ == *s2++ ); 
       if ( !*c ) 
       {
          flag = true; 
          break;
       }
       else
       {
          flag = false;
       }
   }
   return flag;
}
```

However, there are several optimizations I'd like to make

- If possible, would like to get rid of the `flag` as its an extra byte of memory
- The `else { flag = false; }` is a conditional block that is entered most of the time and does the same thing every time it is entered, so I'd like to get rid of this somehow
- Even though the `if ( !*s1 ) return true;` early break helps write the rest of the function more elegantly, I hate having "one special case" condition checking at the beginning of my function. If possible, I'd like the function to be able to start straight into a single loop that encompasses all the logic.

  - The `char * c = *s1` copy in every iteration of the loop is an extra byte that would be nice to get rid of, but I don't know how to get rid of it

Would I write this, then?

Comment: This smells of premature optimization to me. *Why* do you need to make your own function? Why do you need to save one or a few bytes of memory (by removing a variable)? What is the use-case you're working on? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve?

Comment: Before optimization, fix your algorithm, as you may have UB with `while ( *c++ == *s2++ );` without bound check. And incorrect result for case like `("aaba", "aaaba")`. (and you should take `const char*`).

Comment: The code will not work anyway, because while you iterate over the first string, you have to reset the second string to it's start if the chars don't match if the second string can be contained anywhere in the first one. The flags are not neccessary at all.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I love the smell of premature optimization in the morning

Comment: On match fail, you have to reset the second string to it's start, or start+1.

Comment: First of all: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place for this question, here it's just off-topic. Next: there are more urgent issues in this code than removing a single byte of memory - in fact `flag` is just useless. The overall algo is just a plain brute-force search. There are quite a lot of algos for this purpose that are more efficient

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be posted at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . Optimization-questions are off-topic on SO

Comment: Current compilers tend to be bad at auto-vectorizing functions that run for an unknown number of iterations.  This means you can't get good performance without platform-specific code, like SSE intrinsics, even if you were ok with a naive brute-force implementation of `strstr(3)`.  (On most platforms, byte-at-a-time loops are nowhere near as fast as you can go for `memcmp` and detecting a zero byte).  Also note that local variables like `flag` don't necessarily use any stack memory.  It will probably live in a register, if it isn't just optimized into the branch structure of the asm entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the variable `flag` is deceptively easy by the way, as the only cases (using your algorithm as shown) where your function should return `true` is if either `s1` is empty or the condition `!*c` is true. In all other cases it should return `false`.

So your function, ***without any other modifications***, could easily be changed to this:

```
bool contains ( char * s1, char * s2 ) 
{
   // returns true or false depending on whether s1 is contained in s2

   // define that every string contains the empty string
   if ( !*s1 ) return true;

   // search for substrings of s2 that equal s1
   while ( *s2 ) 
   {
       char * c = s1; 
       while ( *c++ == *s2++ ); 
       if ( !*c ) 
            return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `while ( *c++ == *s2++ );`  potentially read past the end of both strings, if they match up to and including the terminating zero byte?  e.g. `contains( same, same )` is a guaranteed segfault.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes it could, but I did add a disclaimer that I didn't do any other modifications to the code, even though some are needed. All I did was remove the need for the `flag` variable.

Answer (score 5):

Do you really need to implement this yourself? First, there exists the function strstr that can solve this problem for you easily, see here for more information: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr

If you really need to implement this yourself, there's no point reinventing the wheel. There are many string search algorithms available, the most common three are:

- [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)
- [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)
- [Rabin-Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm)

Each has their own strengths and weaknesses, read those links for more information.